# What's needed in a Javascript Library to allow use of Import function directly?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I use Angular with vanillajs libraries. There is no problem. Library works fine, but most of the time, I have to do the following

```
declare var MyLib: any;
```

However, for this particular library (CanvasJS), this works...

```
import * as CanvasJS from '../../assets/canvasjs/canvasjs.min.js';
```

What's different, and most importantly how does the library allow import function directly?

Comment: It depends on the library's structure you're currently imported.

Comment: I've tried looking around on JS library tutorials, but none has mention ways to make it 'importable'

Comment: Start here: [import - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import), and then follow the _"See also"_ section for further details

Comment: @Andreas — This seems to be more about TypeScript than JavaScript

Comment: it depends upon the js file being the module or not...if its module we use directly import

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is inside the JS library that you are importing.

In this [repository](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61708451) I've added a showcase using canvasJs, underscoreJs and Jquery. I hope everithing it's explained in the comments [HERE](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61708451/blob/master/src/app/app.component.ts).

Only the latter (jquery) has the need to be defined as a "script" inside the angular.json file ( or inside the index.html file, it's the same ) **because it's not defined as an exportable object** but it's a factory which adds the variable $ to the global context when executed.

So in this case, you don't need to IMPORT it, you just have to "declare" the already present variable in the context to not have TypeScript errors!

As a bonus, the correct way to use JQuery inside an angular project is to install jquery @types, you can find it in this [branch](https://github.com/GaetanoPiazzolla/stackoverflow-question-61708451/tree/correctJquery).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. You guys are the best!